# Getting an empty DataSet table from Oracle Client in .NET

Tags: asp.net, oracle, visual-studio, dataset, dataadapter

Hi have this simple ASPX site setup. In the code behind, I'm connecting to an Oracle database, throwing a `SELECT` query and putting the result to a `DataSet` that I can then use/display on the website.

The problem: The query should give me result (works fine inside SQLDeveloper), but when I'm filling the DataSet, it gives me 0 rows every time. No Oracle errors show up, connection to the database opens up fine and the query looks correct.

I would have liked to get some kind of an Oracle error, that would have been easier to troubleshoot. I have tried to find a solution online, but haven't found anything that has helped with my problem.

Here is the relevant code I'm using:

```
using System.Data.OracleClient;
private OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
-- // Below everyting is in the same method
var ds = new DataSet();
-- // conn.ConnectionString is corretly set
conn.Open(); // connection to database is opened
OracleCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
var sql = "SELECT * FROM someTable"; -- // the SQL query
command.CommandText = sql;
OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
ds.Tables.Clear();
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

Here the `DataSet` (ds) should be full, but it's always empty. Any pointers would be most welcome. Please let me know if I'm missing some information.

Comment: Can you please post the exact query with just names masked.  `=true` is not accepted in Oracle.

Comment: I was indicating that there are parameters in the query, not that I'm using boolean in the query. I fixed it to make it more clear.